# Incorrect event and capture of input area in ask company question on job listing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Looking at a job listing for a company there is a small section like so:

[image]

Here you can ask the company a question, in this case, you want to **Ask Elite Business Solutions a question**.  Clicking this link opens a popup form allowing you to ask them a question.

The input area here, namely **message** `($("[name='message']"))` has the wrong capturing process to enable the button to send a message, namely `$('#send-message')`.  The button only becomes active if you press down on a key (keydown / keyup event).

However, try typing your question in notepad or word and then copy and paste it into this editor **using your mouse to copy and paste**.  The result is the button is still inactive even though content is in there, as shown:

[image]

Please change the jquery event here to use `input` as such:

`$("[name='message']").on('input', function(){ $('#send-message').attr('disabled',false); });`

You can try this out in a console window, steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a job listing like this one https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/105443/aspnet-mvc-full-stack-developer-elite-business-solutions
2. Click the link Ask Elite Business Solutions a question
3. Copy and paste content into the textbox **using your mouse right click and paste**
4. Here is where the bug is...
5. Now open your google chrome or any browser and go to the console window
6. Copy and paste the following snippet of jquery code `$("[name='message']").on('input', function(){ $('#send-message').attr('disabled',false); });` and hit enter to actually trigger this event.
7. Now try to copy and paste into the text box editor.
8. Voila, problem resolved!

Again do all of the copy pasting via your **mouse, not your keyboard**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report Jon. This now works correctly; mouse, keyboard and other devices without the concept of keys.

Comment: It's weird this seems to be an issue with a lot of websites...you can't just monitor keyup / keydown.  I've found this on plenty of sites.  Thanks for fixing this.  I assume a push very soon?

Comment: Yup, pushed to prod already. I suspect that it's an issue because the `input` event is *fairly* new (2012/13 from a brief search) coupled with a developer tendency to use keyboard rather than mouse...? This particular code path hasn't been touched in a while so that's definitely where it comes from on our end!

Comment: Thanks - my suggestion of using `input` was just that, you could do it other ways as well.  Thanks!